# Maintenance message links to serverfault blog

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image: maintenance message with link to blog.serverfault.com]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct.  If there is network maintenance that results in an extended outage, the Server Fault blog is what would be used to communicate that network-wide.